# Structured streaming writes Parquet files to Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I was able to write the results of structured streaming to Parquet files. The thing is that those files are in local file system, and now I want to write them to Hadoop file system. Is there any way to do that?

```java
StreamingQuery query = result //.orderBy("window")
            .repartition(1)
            .writeStream()
            .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
            .format("parquet")
            .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://localhost:19000/data/checkpoints")
            .start("hdfs://localhost:19000/data/total");
```

I used this code, but it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://localhost:19000/data/checkpoints/metadata, expected: file:///
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:649)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamMetadata$.read(StreamMetadata.scala:51)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.<init>(StreamExecution.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:232)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:269)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:262)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:206)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19407

Should be fixed in the next release. You can set the default file system to s3 using `--conf spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS=hdfs://localhost:19000` as a workaround.

Comment: It works, and I used:   SparkSession.builder()
                                    .appName("Spark Data Processing")
                                    .master("local[2]")
                                    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://localhost:19000")
                                    .getOrCreate();

Comment: Yeah, that's same.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me so probably spark upgrade has solved this:

```
option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs:///project/dz/collab/stream/hdfs/chk_ucra").trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("300 seconds")).start("/project/dz/collab/stream/hdfs/ucra")
```